# Bootstrap margin classes are not working on button

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-modal

In my code, adding `m-0` to a button's classes does not work to reduce the margin around the button to 0. But when I add `.close {margin:0;}` into my SCSS file, it works in reducing the margin to 0. I was told not to do this and to use shortened bootstrap classes like `m-0` and `p-0`. So why is adding them to a button not working and how can I make it work in as little code as possible?

`<h2 class="modal-title mx-auto mt-0">My text <br> Hi there </h2> <button type="button" class="close position-absolute m-0" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <i class="fas fa-times" style = "color: #2C757E;"></i> </button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin works fine (Inspect the code and check).

You get space because of the <kbd>space</kbd> (Press spacebar) in your HTML.

[image]

Related: https://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML